# CentOS7上にてパイプ経由rubyを使う方法はありませんか？

Tags: ruby, centos, bash

環境 : CentOS7 ruby2.3.0

```
[root@5ecf1469c888 ~]# irb
2.3.0 :001 > 10.times do |i| `touch #{i}.txt` end
 => 10
2.3.0 :002 > exit
[root@5ecf1469c888 ~]# ls
0.txt  1.txt  2.txt  3.txt  4.txt  5.txt  6.txt  7.txt  8.txt  9.txt  anaconda-ks.cfg  git
```

ワンライナーで何か作業を行う時にパイプなどでrubyに渡して処理させることは可能でしょうか？
上記の例だと、irb環境でシェルを使っているのですが逆のことを行いたいのです。
シェル環境でrubyを使う。

例↓イメージでいうとこのような感じ

```
[root@5ecf1469c888 ~]# ls |irb puts
Switch to inspect mode.
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/magic-file.rb:8:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - puts (Errno::ENOENT)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/magic-file.rb:8:in `open'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/magic-file.rb:8:in `open'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/input-method.rb:101:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/context.rb:85:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/context.rb:85:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:426:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:426:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:381:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:381:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

簡単な例でいうと
ls で標準出力される結果を ruby のputs で表示させる。

他にはパイプで渡した結果を.splitメソッドなどを使ってやりたいのです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rubyのコマンドラインオプション`-ne`を利用します。

（irbは対話的にrubyを扱うコマンドなのでここでは必要ありません）

- `-e <script>` : スクリプトを実行する
- `-n` : 実行するスクリプト全体を `while gets; ... ; end` で囲む
- `$_` : 組み込み変数。getsで読み込んだ値が入っている

例1: 入力を一行ごとに読み込んで出力する

```
$ ls | ruby -ne 'puts $_'
```

例2: 読み込んだ行を分割する (`$F = $_.split` / `-a`オプションが必要)

```
$ ls | ruby -ane 'p $F'
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！教えて頂きました例2つとも出来ました。1つ教えて頂きたいのですが、$F = $_.split と -a の必要性についてです。splitを使うときはかならず$Fなのでしょうか？何か決まっている一覧とかあるのでしょうか？

Comment: 変数`$F`を利用する場合には`-a`オプションが必要です。`$_.split`を使うこともできますが、`p $F[0],$F[1],$F[2]`のような手の込んだことをしたい場合は`$F`の方が簡単に書けます。

Answer (score 3):

入出力をパイプできるプログラムは、「標準入力から読み込み，標準出力へ出力するプログラム」です。

```
#upcase.rb
while $_ = ARGF.gets
  $_.chomp!
  $_.upcase!
  puts $_
end
```

これをパイプで実行するとこうなります。

```
% hostname -f
foo.example.jp
% hostname -f | ruby upcase.rb
FOO.EXAMPLE.JP
% hostname -f | ruby upcase.rb | sed 's/\./%/g'
FOO%EXAMPLE%JP
```

ワンライナーで書く時の簡便のため、rubyに`-n`オプションを指定すると上記の`while`ループが省略できます。`-l`を付けると`$_.chomp!`が省略できます。`-p`を付けると`while`ループと`puts $_`が省略できます。(厳密には少し嘘です)。詳しくは[リファレンスマニュアル](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.3.0/doc/spec=2frubycmd.html)を参照してください。

```
% hostname -f | ruby -lpe '$_.upcase'
FOO.EXAMPLE.JP
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！リファレンスマニュアル助かります。